# Find two special disjoint subsets from a linear transfrom of cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Given a linear transform $T:(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\rightarrow(x_1,x_1+x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$ and a cube $Q=(0,1]^n$. Try to find two disjoint subsets $A,B$ such that for some $t\in\mathbb{R}^n$,

1. $A,B\subseteq T(Q)$
2. $A\bigcup B=T(Q)$
3. $A\bigcup(t+B)=Q$
4. $A\bigcap(t+B)=\emptyset$

I try to consider in the case, $n=3$, then $T$ will be a map that "stretching" the cube to be a rectangle with 2 times longer side-length in y-direction. It will be easy if the 3,4 condition changed to be $A\bigcap(t+B)=Q$ by bisecting the rectangle along y-directional to become two cubes. But I can't think of an example which satisfies the 1 to 4 conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $T$ maps $(x_3,\ldots,x_n)\mapsto(x_3,\ldots,x_n)$ you should consider the case $n=2$ which is far easier zu draw.

First, draw the image $T(Q)$. You can consider how the corner 
$$
T(0,0)=(0,0), ´~T(1,0)=(1,1),~T(0,1)=(0,1)\text{ and }T(1,1)=(1,2)
$$ 
are mapped and connect them or you also can consider the edges 
$$
T(0,x_2)=(0,x_2),~T(x_1,1)=(x_1,x_1+1),~T(1,x_2)=(1,1+x_2)\text{ and }T(x_1,0)=(x_1,x_1).
$$
Then it looks like this:
[image]

Now you might see how you can divide $T(Q)$ in two parts $A$ and $B$ such that (1) to (4) holds. For higher dimension you just have to add the components.

You can see the solution here:

> [image] where $t=\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}$. The formal definition for $A$ and $B$ is up to you.